# Merging frames so i keep only the rows that have the same date

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I want to merge df1 & df2 so i am left with a df based on the 'high' price from df1 column. I think the best approach is to use the 'date' column from df1?. The goal is to line up 'df1 high' with 'df2 datetime' so i can see what time the high was achieved for that day. So i should get back a df with df1 row 0 and df2 row 51.
this is what i have tried -

```
df21 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='date', how='right')#no good
df22 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='date', how='left')#returns nothing
df23 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='date', how='inner')#returns nothing
df26 = pd.merge(df1, df2, right_index=True, left_index=True)#returns nothing
df29 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='date', right_on='date')#returns nothing
df30 = pd.merge(df1, df2, right_index=True, left_index=True)#returns nothing
```

I have the following df1

```
        date   open   high    low  close
0 2017-07-19  30.75  30.84  30.23  30.38
1 2017-07-20  30.44  30.97  29.90  30.52
2 2017-07-21  30.40  31.48  30.30  31.12
3 2017-07-22  31.89  31.98  31.11  31.49
4 2017-07-25  31.85  31.85  29.62  29.78
```

and i have df2

```
              datetime  close   high    low   open   OI     V     WAP  \
49 2017-07-19 10:19:00  30.62  30.70  30.60  30.69   91   196  30.654   
50 2017-07-19 10:20:00  30.68  30.73  30.64  30.64  135   281  30.699   
51 2017-07-19 10:21:00  30.71  30.84  30.69  30.69  383  1156  30.768   
52 2017-07-19 10:22:00  30.73  30.74  30.69  30.70   40    88  30.710   
53 2017-07-19 10:23:00  30.79  30.83  30.74  30.74  165   313  30.796   

          date      time  
49  2017-07-19  10:19:00  
50  2017-07-19  10:20:00  
51  2017-07-19  10:21:00  
52  2017-07-19  10:22:00  
53  2017-07-19  10:23:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to merge on two keys `left_on=['date', 'high']`, `right_on=['date', 'high']`

```
In [709]: df1.merge(df2, left_on=['date', 'high'], right_on=['date', 'high'])
Out[709]:
         date  open_x   high  low_x  close_x             datetime  close_y  \
0  2017-07-19   30.75  30.84  30.23    30.38  2017-07-19 10:21:00    30.71

   low_y  open_y   OI     V     WAP      time
0  30.69   30.69  383  1156  30.768  10:21:00
```

And, then drop or rename columns as you need.

Comment: I miss the old John Galt user name :-(

Comment: thankyou - i didn't realize you can merge on 2 columns and i also had date as different types.